# Angular2/4 best way to change html content periodically

Tags: html, angular, animation

Unfortunately I have to change a html element's content in every X second because I have to show more data in such a little space... I didn't find any good example of change html elements periodically, maybe angular2 animations is a great deal for this but how should I solve the content change in every X time period? 
Btw I have to change a button's content from a div to an other one with different style, elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular is a framework which binds your model to view in a declarative way using templates. All you have to do is update your model periodically and your template will automatically be updated for you.

For example, we can create a dummy observable which will emit every second, and then use the `async` pipe in the template to update it regularly.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `Data: {{ data$ | async }}`,
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data$ = Observable.interval(400).mapTo(1).scan((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}
```

Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8zrgd3?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts).

Of course, details depend on the way you're receving your data and the way you want to display it, but the above example shows that it's very simple to change the HTML content periodically which was your question.

Comment: hmm, I just hope there is a 'better' way to do it :( I already implemented a way where I use an observable just like you and manipulate the template though 2 *ngIf.. btw great code, but the real question is if this is the official way to do this things, or there is an other better one? :)

Comment: I don't see how it can get better than this to be honest. Can you describe what exactly it is you're looking for?

Comment: sure, I have a button which contains a lot of elements, but unfortunately on this button I have to display +2-3 information sometimes, and there is no place for them on the button... so I thought what if I try to rotate this information in every 4-5second to display all the necessary information for the user

Comment: I fail to see how this answer doesn't cover that topic. Create an interval where you loop over the values you want to be displayed. Use the modulo operator to loop over the sum.